# Logical Grouping in Bigquery

Tags: group-by, google-bigquery

I am trying to group data in bigquery that goes beyond simple aggregation. However I am not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible. 
The idea behind the data:

One employee will be logged in and can perform multiple transactions. hits.eventInfo captures all of this data but the only field that separates the transactions from one another is a flight_search field which is done to look up a person's records before a transaction (I also thought about using the resetting hitNumber as a transaction separator, but its not always a clean reset per transaction).

**My question is, is it possible to group by the fullVisitorId+VisitId, date and this logic where we would have all of the `array_agg` reset each time the *flight_search* field is fired?** Currently, all the transactional data is in going into one array instead of separate arrays per transaction. Its then impossible to tell which fields go with which transaction. Further, taking the **max** is supposed to give me the last updates in each transaction, but it just gives me the last transaction because they are all together.

Example of my query below. I have to use array_agg or something like it since the subqueries can only have one return

```sql
WITH eventData AS (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(fullVisitorId, ' ', CAST(VisitId AS string)) sessionId,
    date AS date,
    hit.hour AS checkinHour,
    hit.minute AS checkinMin,
    (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(hit.eventInfo.eventAction) FROM UNNEST(hits) hit WHERE hit.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'pnr') AS pnr,
    (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(hit.eventInfo.eventAction)) AS val FROM UNNEST(hits) hit WHERE hit.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'submit_checkin') AS names
  FROM
    `web-analytics.192016109.ga_sessions_20191223`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hit
    ## group by sessionId, date, hit.eventInfo.eventCategory ='flight_search'
 )

SELECT
  sessionId,
  date,
  MAX(checkinHour) chkHr,
  MAX(checkinMin) AS chkMin,
  # end of transaction
  MAX(pnr[ORDINAL(ARRAY_LENGTH(pnr))]) AS pnr,
  names.eventAction AS pax_name
FROM
  eventData,
  UNNEST (names) AS names
GROUP BY
  sessionId,
  date,
  pax_name
```

Technically if I add a group by here, everything will break because Ill be asked to then group by hour, min and then hits which is an array...

Example test data

This is the original eventData as it is fed in from Google Analytics to BigQuery. I have simplified the displayed eventCategories. This is where the inner query is sourcing. A transaction is completed after the submit_checkin event happens. As we can see though, there is one pnr (identifier) but multiple people are checked-in for that pnr.

[image]
This is a sample of the output from eventData looks like. As you can see, the pnrs are grouped in one array and the names are in one array. Its not directly possible to see which were together in which transaction. 
[image]

Lastly, here is the whole query output. I wrote on the picture what the expected result is. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see which information was tracked in the same hit you should keep the relation between them. But it seems they are not in the same hit with eventCategory being 'pnr' one time and 'submit_checkin' the other time.
I'm not sure it's intentional but you're also cross joining the table with hits ... and then you're array_agg()-ing the hits array per hit again. That seems wrong.

If you're staying on session scope then there is no need to group anything, because the table already comes with 1 row = 1 session.

This query prepares another window function

```sql
SELECT
  fullVisitorId, 
  visitstarttime,
  date,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      hitNumber,
      IF(eventInfo.eventCategory='flight_search' 
           AND 
           LAG(eventInfo.eventCategory) OVER (ORDER BY hitnumber ASC) = 'submit_checkin', 1, 0
        ) as breakInfo,
      eventInfo,
      hour,
      minute
    FROM UNNEST(hits) hit 
    WHERE hit.eventInfo.eventCategory IN ('pnr', 'submit_checkin', 'flight_search')
    ORDER BY hitnumber ASC
  ) AS myhits1,
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT
    *,
    SUM(breakInfo) OVER (order by hitnumber) as arrayId
  FROM (SELECT 
      hitNumber,
      IF(eventInfo.eventCategory='flight_search' 
           AND 
           LAG(eventInfo.eventCategory) OVER (ORDER BY hitnumber ASC) = 'submit_checkin', 1, 0
        ) as breakInfo,
      eventInfo,
      hour,
      minute
    FROM UNNEST(hits) hit 
    WHERE hit.eventInfo.eventCategory IN ('pnr', 'submit_checkin', 'flight_search')
    ORDER BY hitnumber ASC
  )) AS myhits2
FROM
  `web-analytics.192016109.ga_sessions_20191223`
```

This gives you a number as id to group by. You only need to feed the output that gets fed to the array function to yet another sub-query that finally groups it into arrays using `array_agg()` and `group by arrrayId`.

Comment: Martin, I think you are right by the critique. The query provided is a better place to start. But, as I mentioned before, the issue of not being able to separate the transactions is still an issue. I have edited your answer with the results of the query you posted.

Comment: Looking at this data it seems like multiple transactions can have the same pnr? E.g. hit 105 is a pnr and 109 and 110 are transactions. Is this a tracking problem or am I not understanding the data?

Comment: If you want the latest pnr for any given transaction you can do so with window functions. But I need to understand the data first.

Comment: Martin, this is airline test data. A pnr is a reservation and can have multiple people checked-in under that reservation (there are a lot of fields I excluded to make the data simpler). A transaction starts by searching for a flight. So I want to separate the transactions within each google analytics sessions by this field `flight_search`. I updated the picture to show the separation of transactions.

Comment: I hope the edits bring you onto the right track. If you need more help please give me the outputs of that query - I'm writing this kinda blind ;)

Comment: `Error: Encountered "" at line 6, column 5.` I dont understand this query enough to know how to fix this error. Im not sure blocking the data in this way will work as with the actual data, the `submit_checkin` is not always the last event fired. I can assume is that `flight_search` is first because there is a large gap in the hit time. With the rest of the events, they get mixed up more times than not. Thank you really for the help so far. I was not aware of window functions, but I am looking into them now.

Comment: could you try the query again?

Comment: Hey Martin, thank you so much! That worked. I updated the ifs to match my data exactly, but the ideas I learned from your query helped me through the end. Do you have a Patreon? Or Paypal? I really want to show my appreciation! :)

Comment: Would you mind helping me with another question about the same data? Im not sure if my questions are not clear/not framed correctly. If you have the time, the question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686250/columnize-row-based-event-data-where-each-event-category-can-be-represented-mult